# How can I have a field that accepts two different mask formats?

Tags: reactjs, input-mask

I'm creating a form and using the react-input-mask component. The user can have two different formats of phone number, these being "(99) 9999-9999" or "(99) 9 9999-9999".

I have read the docs but can't tell how to make the following field to accept these 2 formats and sort of "adapt" as the user types. Thanks in advance!

```
<InputMask onBlur={(e) => this.handleBlur('telefone', e.target.value)}
           type="text"
           defaultValue={new_item.telefone}                        
           class='inputTextCriar'
           mask="(99) 9999-9999">
</InputMask>
```

Answer (score 0):

As someone that never used this component, I think the quickest way to solve is to add some logic on the mask property

```
const mask = value.length === 11 ? "(99) 9 9999-9999" : "(99) 9999-9999"
<InputMask
 mask={mask}
 ...
/>
```

Comment: I get what you tried to do, but it didn't work, it just didn't format at all. also, the way you suggested, value won't be defined, I tried using an arrow function and testing the length of target.event.value. Still didn't work